# TYPO3 Extension: 'Unknown column in field list' error

Tags: typo3

Basically: Every time I add a new class/model with the extension_builder and then want to create a record of that class I get the following error message:

> 2: SQL error: 'Unknown column 'edited' in 'field list''
>   (tx_icingaconfgen_domain_model_checkperiod:NEW5a27f9da8a41d636846075)

The interesting thing is: "edited" is NOT a property of that class, but the property of other classes in that extension. I've searched through the TCA of the class that throws the error and also the MySql table itself, but the field "edited" is indeed not part of that class. What's going on here?

Edit: What I find interesting is the fact that when I add a column "edited" to MySql table manually, the record can be created. But in no way I'm using this property in my Model. Why does it require a MySql column of that name then?

Comment: Need more information about checkperiod: Code of model, TCA and SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it  turned out the culprit was actually this line of code in the ext_localconf.php:

```
$GLOBALS ['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processDatamapClass']['extkey'] = 'Cjk\\Icingaconfgen\\Hook\\EvalHook';
$GLOBALS ['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processCmdmapClass']['extkey'] = 'Cjk\\Icingaconfgen\\Hook\\EvalHook';
```

It's a hook that I've implemented into my extension that just marks if a record has been edited in the BE or not.  I actually use this Hook that whenever a record is edited changes the propety edited from 0 to 1. This is intended of course, but the class checkperiod doesn't have the property 'edited'. But since the hook for the Datamapper works with every record that is changed or created it also tries to change 'edited' in classes that don't have this property. A simple if condition in the Hook itself, if the key 'edited' of the $fieldArray is NULL solved my problem.

```
class EvalHook {
    function processDatamap_postProcessFieldArray($status, $table, $id, &$fieldArray, &$pObj) {


            if($status == "update" && $table != 'tx_icingaconfgen_domain_model_checkperiod'){
            $fieldArray[edited] = 1;
            }
            elseif($status != "update" && $table != 'tx_icingaconfgen_domain_model_checkperiod){
                $fieldArray[edited] = 0;
            }


            }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code I can only guess whats going on. Surely the field is requiered when a record is persisted. So it is possible that you referenced it in your TCA. If not in the `columns` maybe in the `ctrl` section:

```
'ctrl' => [
    'tstamp' => 'tstamp',
    'crdate' => 'crdate',
    'cruser_id' => 'cruser_id',
    ...
],
```

These fields are updated automatically if a recods is changed or created. There are more of those fields. So check your `ctrl` section.

It is also possible that you map another property (possibly even of another class) to that database field in your TypoScript like this:

```
plugin.tx_myextension {
    persistence {
        classes {
            MyVendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Person {
                mapping {
                    tableName = tt_address
                    recordType = \MyVendor\MyExtension\Domain\Model\Person
                    columns {
                        birthday.mapOnProperty = dateOfBirth
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example taken from [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/6-Persistence/4-use-foreign-data-sources.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the problem was actually something completely different as it turned out. I actually use a Hook that whenever a record is edited changes the propety edited from 0 to 1. This is intended of course, but the class checkperiod doesn't have the property 'edited'. But since the hook for the Datamapper works with every record that is changed or created it also tries to change 'edited' in classes that don't have this property. A simple if condition if the key 'edited' of the $fieldArray is NULL solved my problem.