# SOLVED: TYPO3 Controller: Unknown column 'uid' in 'field list' while bulk insert

Tags: php, sql, doctrine, typo3, typo3-extensions

First of all, I'm using TYPO3 9.5.9 and the Doctrine QueryBuilder/ConnectionPool.

I've tried to do some backup and restore from the controller side. I've managed to get to the restore point so far, my controller restore code:

```
public static function loadBackup(array $backupSettings):int {
    $affectedRows = 0;
    $tableNames = explode(',', $backupSettings['tableNames']);
    $tablePrefix = $backupSettings['tablePrefix'];
    $backupPath = $backupSettings['path']. date("Ymd")."/";
    foreach($tableNames as $table){

        $queryBuilder = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConnectionPool::class)
        ->getConnectionForTable($tablePrefix . $table);

        $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($backupPath . $tablePrefix . $table . '.csv'));
        array_walk($csv, function(&$a) use ($csv) {
          $a = array_combine($csv[0], $a);
        });
        $headers = $csv[0];
        array_shift($csv);
        $affectedRows += $queryBuilder->bulkInsert(
            $tablePrefix . $table,
            $csv,
            $headers
        );
    }
    return $affectedRows;
}
```

This code is working so far, but i get an exception running the restore:

````
 [ERROR] An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO `tx_****_domain_model_link` (`uid`, `pid`, `tstamp`,    
     `crdate`, `cruser_id`, `deleted`, `hidden`, `datasource`, `sha1`, `title`, `url`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 
     ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["900000000", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "", "```", ""]:                                  
                                                                                                                    
     Unknown column 'uid' in 'field list'                                                                          
     Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\InvalidFieldNameException thrown in line 60 in file                                    
     /var/www/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php
````

First, i thought the uid was missing in the db/definition, but no:

```
CREATE TABLE tx_****_domain_model_link (
uid int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
pid int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',

datasource smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
sha1 varchar(40) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
title varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
url varchar(1024) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (uid));
```

And even in the DB, the field is there:
[image: Table definition]

If i try to add the Query manually via the backend, i get the same error. If i try to add a new Entry using the "New dataset" Button in the adminer Dashboard, it works. Even if i copy the command and add the entry again with a different ID it works - so what am I missing during the controller restore?

Working Command:

```
INSERT INTO `tx_****_domain_model_link` (`uid`, `pid`, `tstamp`, `crdate`, `cruser_id`, `deleted`, `hidden`, `datasource`, `sha1`, `title`, `url`) VALUES ('23123123', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '', '', '');
```

Any help is very appreciated!

BR,
Martin

**UPDATE: Solution found:**

Okay, i found out the mistake.

Unfortunately the solution hints from @GNB didn't help me to get to the correct result.

However, i've tried to encapsulate the cells in the csv with `"<value>"` and: it works!

Anyway, i changed the backup mechanism from

- Export to csv
- Import from csv

to:

- Copy table to backup table, which is created before having the same schema (CREATE .. LIKE ..)
- Just copy the values back in, in case of error

Thanks for your help.

BR,
Martin

Comment: Please don't put the solution in the question. This is why we have answers. If you have a unique answer that worked then put it in as a separate answer. Not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not actually sure, but combining some answer related to this question,

- Missing field in table
- Calling Hook (From somewhere in your extension list)

#### Missing field:

Obviously, you have the field as you gave the image.

#### Calling Hook (From somewhere in your extension list)

Sometimes external can be the reason for such an issue. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47771919/5961782) @Mondblut explained this well.

#### Database table issue

Database table glitch could be there as well. I'm not really sure this can be the case. But, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63718047/5961782) is the trick by @Christiane!

Also, if you have some other copies of your extension this can be a conflict. Follow the instruction from @Sybille [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63728832/5961782).

Hope this will be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found out the mistake.

Unfortunately the solution hints from @GNB didn't help me to get to the correct result.

However, I've tried to encapsulate the cells in the csv with `"<value>"` and: it works!

Anyway, I changed the backup mechanism from

- Export to csv
- Import from csv

to:

- Copy table to backup table, which is created before having the same schema (CREATE .. LIKE ..)
- Just copy the values back in, in case of error